# When logging into a site, I had checked my computer to save the information. Now I want to remove it. How can I?

Tags: windows-7, password-management

I logged onto a site & Windows 7 popped up the box to save the user name & password. I click on it  to save my information. I want to remove it from the computer so I will have to type my information in each time. How can I do this?  Thanks

Comment: Please refer to the Window help file for IE on clearing saved information.

Comment: Which browser? IE? Firefox? Chrome? Safari? Opera? Then, which version? You could have provided a BIT more information. I'm amazed you found superuser.com considering the answer to this question is all over the internet.

Comment: Sorry. I use IE. This is the first time I have been on here. I have gotten some good advice from people. Thanks for ALL your help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the stored password from the browser. These steps differ depending on your primary browser. Since you didn't specify here are the steps for three most common (Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome):

Internet Explorer 10:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Fill-in-website-forms-and-passwords-automatically

(For Internet Explorer after the AutoComplete settings dialog box opens click Manage Passwords afterwards)

Firefox:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords

Chrome:

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95606

Comment: Sorry about the Internet Explorer document, but I had a lot of trouble finding a good source. It seems that these settings for IE are found in the Control Panel (silly putting them in separate locations). However this article should be a little better: [Managing Saved Passwords - Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/manage-stored-passwords)

Answer (score 1):

From your question...

Internet options - Browsing History - Delete... make sure you check Form Data and Passwords.

or

Control Panel - All Control Panel Items - credential Manager

Check for the saved account under Generic Credentials